# mysql query dynamic update

Tags: php, mysql, forms, phpmyadmin

> **RESOLVED**

I have a mysql table (table1) with many columns with a single ID.

**table name:** table1

**columns:** from "pt1 to pt1000"

**id** = 1

- I have a query that updates the data in the columns, 10 data at a time
- I would need a unique and dynamic query that inserts the 10 values ​​in sequence at each submission.

**example**:

1. send query update command (from php form)
2. I insert the 10 values ​​in the columns from "pt1" to "pt10"
3. send query update command with other data (from the same php form)
4. I insert the 10 values ​​in the columns from "pt11" to "pt21" and so on

**Question:** How can I set the query so that it knows to insert the values ​​in the right columns and not always in the same ones?

Thanks to all help me

------------------ **EDIT** -----------------------------

I resolve passing manual (input and select value) from php form to php page of query and insert this value in variable to construct dynamical query.

**For example:**

IN PHP FORM:
have two select

1 - Select DB (value = "name_db_i_want_to_update")

2 - Select Column ( value = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,etc")

IN PHP QUERY PAGE:

1. Select DB Value as "$ db"
2. Select Column as "$ set"
3. IF statement with piece of query set. IF column value = 1 ELSE IF etc, $ setquery = pt1 = "value1","value2" etc.
4. Construct dynamical query ( UPDATE $db SET $setquery WHERE id=1 )

it is not the best solution, certainly also wrong as a programming logic, but it works.

**Thanks to all for help**

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: `columns: from "pt1 to pt1000"` - this is a sign of a poorly designed database. You might want to rethink your approach. What do these columns represent?

Comment: Why do you have 1000 columns, and not 10 + a field indicating if you need the first, 2nd, 3rd, 4th .. 100th group of fields?

Comment: I haven't tried anything because I don't know what to feel. I have a query update that works but on preset values ​​by hand. So for each entry I would have to change the query by hand.

I had thought of preparing X php file with preset queries and calling the right one through a select in the php form, I would solve it but it is very cumbersome and takes a long time.

I have no idea if you can set up an update query to insert values ​​starting from the first column that doesn't have a null value for example ?? Thank you

Comment: You are running into these problems because your database design is bad (and that's an understatement). Writing to a database should not be this complicated or cumbersome. You need to restructure your tables. These should probably be rows in a different table, not columns. But I'm just guessing.

Comment: @El_Vanja : the columns represent text value with a question from php form.

yes you are right, thanks. I will consider the option of reformulating the structure.

Comment: @Luuk : i don't know, i'm no mysql expert. I had set up the database in this way and currently it is already implemented with other functions so it would not be convenient for me to change the setting

Comment: So these are a 1000 answers to a 1000 different questions?

Comment: @El_Vanja no there are 1000 columns with null value. through extension I make a web page scrape of 10 questions at a time and I have to insert them in the respective columns of the db.

Comment: Well, that certainly sounds like they should be rows, with a column indicating your number from 1 to 1000 (whatever meaning these numbers hold).

Comment: Please show how you created this table..... because "that certainly sounds like they ARE rows".   (/me asking why you did not get this error "ERROR 1118 (42000): Row size too large. The maximum row size for the used table type, not counting BLOBs, is 65535.")

Comment: thos should be done in a stored procudre and dynamic  sql

Comment: @nbk, No, It should be done using a correct database design...

Comment: @Luuk i thought about makeíng a three column design, but he wants to insert date sequentially, the data nbelong to one id and will be displayed in that way, so there will be no need to redesign the table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouild change your design to somethingk like mytable2, to gather the data will be a bit more sql programming needed, but it should be a one time thing to get your data in the form  you need.

If you insist on keeping your design, you can use a stored procedure like blow to fill your table, but you have to know the sequence where the belong, this could be automated as well, with another table wherre you have the already filled data position stored
, but the basic principle of dynamic sql is the same.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE mytable2(id int, pos int, value int)
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO mytable2 VALUES (1,1,1),(1,2,2),(1,3,3),(1,4,4),(1,5,5),(1,6,6)
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE mytable(id int, pt1 int, pt2 int, pt3 int, pt4 int, pt5 int, pt6 int)
> ```

> ```
> CREATE PROCEDURE `new_routine` (_id int, _sequence int, _pt1 int, _pt2 int,_pt3 int)
> BEGIN
>
>     IF _sequence = 0 then
>        SET @sql := CONCAT('INSERT INTO mytable (id,pt1,pt2,pt3) VALUES (',_id,',',_pt1,',',_pt2,',',_pt3,')');
>     ELSE
>        SET @sql := CONCAT('UPDATE mytable SET pt',1 +((_sequence -1) * 3) ,'= ',_pt1
>                           ,', pt',2 +((_sequence -1) * 3) ,'= ',_pt2
>                           ,', pt',3 +((_sequence -1) * 3) ,'= ',_pt3,' WHERE id = ',_id);
>     END IF;
>
>     PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
>     EXECUTE stmt;
>     DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
> END
> ```

> ```
> CALL new_routine(1,0,1,1,1);
> ```

> ```
> CALL new_routine(1,1,2,2,2)
> ```

> ```
> CALL new_routine(1,2,3,3,3)
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM mytable
> ```
>
> ```
> id | pt1 | pt2 | pt3 | pt4 | pt5 | pt6
> -: | --: | --: | --: | --: | --: | --:
>  1 |   2 |   2 |   2 |   3 |   3 |   3
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM mytable2
> ```
>
> ```
> id | pos | value
> -: | --: | ----:
>  1 |   1 |     1
>  1 |   2 |     2
>  1 |   3 |     3
>  1 |   4 |     4
>  1 |   5 |     5
>  1 |   6 |     6
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=56bff132a20bb3d80e6f28d64591fdec)*