# Insert date into multiple table or create one table with more column and store at once

Tags: mysql

Suppose I have several user tables i.e user_table1, user_table2, user_table3, user_table..... . I have created this because if I create single-user table, it will create approx 150 columns. So I separated it with fewer columns table. In user_table1 user_id is set to primary key and rest of the table I set user_id as a foreign key.

user_table1

```
 -------------------------------------------
| user_id | column1 | column2 | column.....|
 -------------------------------------------
|   1     | value 1 | value 2 | value .....|
 -------------------------------------------
```

user_table2

```
 -----------------------------------------------
| user_id(fk) | column1 | column2 | column.....|
 -----------------------------------------------
|   1         | value 1 | value 2 | value .....|
 -----------------------------------------------
```

user_table3

```
 -----------------------------------------------
| user_id(fk) | column1 | column2 | column.....|
 -----------------------------------------------
    ------ ----- --------- ----- ------- -----
```

The first table is generally stored for login details and some other value when the user register. So my question is after registration when user edit their profile (profile details value will store into another table i.e  user_table2,  user_table3) how to insert to another table? Is this method is ok or I should create one table with 150 columns?

Comment: Have a look at the answer in this question, and the give answer: [mysql query dynamic update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67557042/mysql-query-dynamic-update).   There might be another answer but it is unclear what you are doing with all those `user_tableX` tables with `columnX` fields in them.

Comment: A table with 150 columns sounds strange - is this a normalized structure?

Comment: Yep, read that chapter on normalisation over again.

Comment: (Model first and thoroughly. Sticking to *enter data using stored procedures, retrieve via views* limits the number of places to account for a change in schema. If and when you can identify a set of attributes larger than its complement that *none of which is set and will not be* in more than half the entities/rows, it *might* save a little space with dubious effect on time required - postpone to when you need to kill time, estimate time to invest and gains to be achieved, measure!)

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of a case where multiple tables that all have a 1:1 relationship to each other do anything other than add complexity to working with them since simple look-ups become joins, etc.  If you really don't have duplicated information, one large table is probably easier to work with.  If you are having data repeated across multiple users, then you should probably reevaluate your schema and set up tables that represent different types of information.